# Return a json from inside a schema in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following document:

```
{
  "id": "someString",
  "servers": [
    {
      "name": "ServerName",
      "bases": [
        {
          "name": "Base 1",
          "status": true
        },
        {
          "name": "Base 2",
          "status": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to create an API route to get a json that contains only the names of the bases that status are true.

My current dependencies of my project are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "basic-auth": "^1.1.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.1",
    "express": "~4.0.0",
    "mongoose": "~4.6.8",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^1.0.4",
    "morgan": "~1.0.0"
  }
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

@Edit

Forgot to mention, I'm using mongoose.Schema to archtect objects:

```
var ClienteSchema = new Schema({
  id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  servers: [{
    nome : String,
    bases: [{
      nome: String,
      status: Boolean
    }]
  }]
});
```

The difficulty is to navigate into the `Cliente > servers > bases` to get the `status` and return the `nome` of the base... :(

Comment: have you tried using a db.find() with some query parameters inside the find method?

Comment: db.yourcollection.find({servers : {bases : {status : true}}}); should return all the values u want

Comment: @mnemosdev I have this:
`router.route('/backup/:id')
  .get(auth, (req,res) => {
    Cliente.find({
      id : req.params.id
    }, (err, result) => {
        (err) ? res.send(err) : res.json(result);
    });
  });`

Comment: that query returns a single json object, not a collection of objects to search from

Comment: you have 2 options, 1st and easiest is process the data in node after getting it back from mongoDB and second is do lookup Aggregation in mongoDB

Comment: @mnemosdev tried this `find()` you posted, I got an empty array :(

Comment: @MujtabaKably I'll research about the Aggregation in mongoDB, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ViníciusRufine  `Aggregation Pipeline` of mongoDB, its equivalent to CTE or Temp Tables of SQL

Comment: @MujtabaKably by reading OP code it seems that he has only 1 document returned which contains a lot of information that he needs, wouldn't he just need to do a search inside the object, in which case this topic is about objects in javascript and not mongodb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below aggregation.

The below query uses [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to traverse `servers` array in place and  keep the `name` and followed with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to keep the `bases` with `status` value true to transform the output.

```
Model.aggregate({
    $project: {
        id: 1,
        servers: {
            $map: {
                input: "$servers",
                as: "server",
                in: {
                    name: "$$server.name",
                    bases: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$$server.bases",
                            as: "base",
                            cond: {
                                $eq: ["$$base.status", true]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).exec(function(err, user) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
})
```

Sample Response:

```
{
    "id": "someString",
    "servers": [{
        "name": "ServerName",
        "bases": [{
            "name": "Base 1",
            "status": true
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Damn, I'm a bit lost in this code but worked. Returned only my `status : true` bases. I'll have to study this code and mongoDB aggregate to understand better what happened there!

Comment: nice answer, he could just traverse the returned json object tho

Comment: @mnemosdev Yeah you can do that on client side. It was just another option.

Comment: @veeram can't you also do it on the server-side once the document is returned from the query?

Comment: @mnemosdev  yes that's what I meant in previous comment. You can do it using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your document is Mongo model. If so, I named it Foo.

```
var Foo = require(./path/to/foo);

Foo.find({ 'servers.bases.status': true })
    .select('servers.bases.name')
    .exec(function(err, name) {
         // your business
    });
});
```

Tell me if I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: wont this return all records who has even 1 `server.bases.status` as true.

Comment: OP has a single document from which he derives multiple true and false server statuses, this finds multiple servers but does not bind well with OP code which he posted in his own question's comments

Comment: this is what OP wrote router.route('/backup/:id') .get(auth, (req,res) => { Cliente.find({ id : req.params.id }, (err, result) => { (err) ? res.send(err) : res.json(result); }); });

Comment: @NERDYLIZARD that code worked well to list all bases from a server, but returned even the bases that `status` were `false`, is there a way to return only the `status : true` bases?

Comment: @ViníciusRufine oh, try `true` instead of `'true'` if status is boolean